# Property of Count function with NULL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, null

- Why `SELECT COUNT(1+NULL)` returns `0` even though `SELECT 1+NULL` returns `NULL`
- Relatively why `SELECT COUNT(NULL)` returns error message `Operand data type void type is invalid for count operator` even though `SELECT NULL` returns `NULL`

Need explanation.

Comment: Good question, I think you can start by reading this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why SELECT COUNT(1+NULL) returns 0 even though SELECT 1+NULL returns NULL

Performing any operation with NULL will return NULL.  So 1+NULL will return NULL.  The select returns the single value (which is NULL) because that is the result of the calculation.

`COUNT()` works differently depending on what it is counting.  `COUNT(*)` returns the cardinality of the refered-to table i.e. the number of rows.  Put an expression inside the brackets, however, and `COUNT()` will eliminate NULLs; 1+NULL is NULL so COUNT(1+NULL) eliminates the one value you have provided and returns 0.

> Relatively why SELECT COUNT(NULL) returns error message Operand data type void type is invalid for count operator even though SELECT NULL returns NULL.

`NULL` has no implicit type so `COUNT()` doesn't know how to handle it and throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

`1 + null` is `null` , but `count()` aggregate Counts are not null , it's not like sum.
your example is like `Sum(1 +null)` : = `null`

see :`SELECT SUM(1+ NULL),COUNT(1+ NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

If we perform any arithmetic operation with NULL, the result will be `NULL`. So we need to convert this NULL value to something and can do the operation.

> See this link **[Nulls and Aggregate Functions](http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-12656.html)**

Comment: Nice demonstrations between NULL and aggregate functions

Answer (score 0):

The COUNT() form of the COUNT aggregate function returns the count of all non-null values.  This is described in the SQL Server Books Online (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx): "evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the number of nonnull values."  Your first example passes a single NULL value so the resultant count is zero.

Regarding the "operand data type void" error, the error message is clearer in SQL Server 2012 and later versions.  In versions after SQL Server 2008 R2 you will get message "operand data type NULL is invalid for count operator." due to the unknown data type.  The behavior is different when an untyped NULL expression is returned directly by a SELECT statement.  In that case, SQL Server uses data type int implicitly for the expression meta-data.